# bitbake/wic error when making squashfs file systems

Tags: filesystems, yocto, bitbake, squashfs, yocto-wic

When I specify the **squashfs** file system type in the `wic` kickstart file (*.wks* file):

```
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label bootfs   --uuid 69AE36A5-1C24-412C-89F4-5E8D9123376C --fixed-size 32M
part       --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label bootfs_2 --uuid AD4023AC-6F63-4598-A32B-7B7864BA6796 --fixed-size 32M
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=squashfs --uuid 3C51A271-215E-49B7-824F-4CF56F8BEE0D --fixed-size 176M
part   --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=squashfs --uuid 8B9C88D2-3CC6-4B2E-A8A0-20AEF87D06DA --fixed-size 176M
part --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label fdb --uuid 6D7EEEDA-CD5E-4A8F-94DC-8670DDF887FA --fixed-size 8M

bootloader --ptable gpt
```

`bitbake` ends with the following error:

> DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
> DEBUG: Executing shell function do_image_wic
> INFO: Creating image(s)...
>
> ERROR: A native program mksquashfs required to build the image was not found (see details above).
>
> Please make sure wic-tools have squashfs-tools-native in its DEPENDS, build it with 'bitbake wic-tools' and try again.

How do I specify the dependency ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency can be put in the machine configuration file with the `WKS_FILE_DEPENDS` variable. For example:

```
[...]
WKS_FILE = "my_wic_conf.wks"
WKS_FILE_DEPENDS += "squashfs-tools-native"
```